# Installing AMD RX 5700 XT proprietary drivers on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: multiple-monitors, 20.04, amdgpu

I use the following setup:

- AMD RX 5700 XT gpu
- Two AOC G2460PG Display Port.
- Ubuntu 20.04.

I installed [the official driver package](https://www.amd.com/en/support/graphics/amd-radeon-5700-series/amd-radeon-rx-5700-series/amd-radeon-rx-5700-xt).

Still I get a very low resolution. How can I fix this?

**EDIT 1**
When I try to add the missing resolution with `xrandr`, the screens go blank.

Comment: When I try to add the missing resolution with xrandr the screens go blank.

Comment: Was there a problem with the installation of the driver? Any errors?

Comment: None what so ever everything seems fine.
I have the same problem when I use my Intel UHD 630.

Comment: I now know what the problem is.
My monitors do not provide a valid EDID.

Comment: So I could get the correct modeline, and it works for one session.
How can I make this persistent?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.

Here are the modelines for your display:

```
  Detailed timing #1....... 1920x1080p at 85Hz (16:9)
    Modeline............... "1920x1080" 198,500 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080
    1083 1088 1124 +hsync -vsync
  Detailed timing #2....... 1920x1080p at 100Hz (16:9)
    Modeline............... "1920x1080" 235,500 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1133 +hsync -vsync
  Detailed timing #3....... 1920x1080p at 120Hz (16:9)
    Modeline............... "1920x1080" 285,500 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1144 +hsync -vsync
  Detailed timing #4....... 1920x1080p at 144Hz (16:9)
    Modeline............... "1920x1080" 325,080 1920 1944 1976 2056 1080 1083 1088 1098 +hsync +vsync
```

1. Check if they work with the following commands:

   ```
    xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_85.00" 198.500 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1124 +Hsync -Vsync
    xrandr --addmode DisplayPort-0 "1920x1080_85.00"
    xrandr --output DisplayPort-0 --mode "1920x1080_85.00"
   ```
2. If they work make a `20-monitor.conf` at `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`:

   ```
   Section "Monitor"
       Identifier "Displayport-0"
       Modeline "1920x1080_85.00" 198.500 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1124 +hsync -vsync
       Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080_85.00"
   EndSection

   Section "Screen"
       Identifier "Screen0"
       Monitor "Displayport-0"
       DefaultDepth 24
       SubSection "Display"
           Modes "1920x1080_85.00"
       EndSubSection
   EndSection

   Section "Device"
       Identifier "Device0"
       Driver "amdgpu"
   EndSection
   ```

That should fix your problem.

[This page for monitor settings on the Arch wiki provides clarification](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xorg#Monitor_settings)