# AOC G2460PG on Ubuntu 20.04 resolution stuck at 640x480 on Intel Integrated Graphics UHD 630 can't get 1920x1080

Tags: graphics, xorg, intel-graphics, display-resolution

I'm using Intel integrated graphics UHD 630. I have an AOC G2460PG monitor which seems to have issues with the driver and my resolution is stuck at 640x480. I found a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1250254/aoc-g2460pg-on-ubuntu-20-04-640x480-radeon-5700-xt) that works except I'm not sure about the second part because I don't have a `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf` directory. After reviewing the [UbuntuWiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config) I see that it's located in `/etc/X11`, but I don't know what settings I should put in there or if I should even make the same file/path `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-headless.conf` for Ubuntu. Any help here would be appreciated. As of now I'm resorting to doing the first step from cli after each reboot because the settings don't save, but at least I can get 1920x1080 resolution this way.

These are the commands I use after rebooting:

```
$ xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_85.00" 198.500 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1124 +Hsync -Vsync
$ xrandr --addmode DP-1 "1920x1080_85.00"
$ xrandr --output DP-1 --mode "1920x1080_85.00"
```

I tried adding the following to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-monitor.conf`:

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "DP-1"
    Modeline "1920x1080_85.00" 198.500 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1124 +hsync -vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080_85.00"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Monitor "DP-1"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "1920x1080_85.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "intel"
EndSection
```

That didn't working. Here is my output for `xrandr --query --verbose` :

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (0x765) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  45604
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:     HDMI-1
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Fixed_Point, RGB_Wide_Gamut_Floating_Point, opRGB, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, BT2020_RGB, BT601_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_YCC
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 95 
        supported: 95
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
  1024x768 (0x46) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x47) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  800x600 (0x48) 36.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock  35.16KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock  56.25Hz
  848x480 (0x49) 33.750MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   848 start  864 end  976 total 1088 skew    0 clock  31.02KHz
        v: height  480 start  486 end  494 total  517           clock  60.00Hz
  640x480 (0x4a) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
  1920x1080_85.00 (0x765) 198.500MHz +HSync -VSync *current
        h: width  1920 start 1968 end 2000 total 2080 skew    0 clock  95.43KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1083 end 1088 total 1124           clock  84.90Hz
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  45604
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:     DP-1
    CRTCs:      0 1 2
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    HDCP Content Type: HDCP Type0 
        supported: HDCP Type0, HDCP Type1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 105 
        supported: 105
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

After a few attempts/edits the following configuration worked for me

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Displayport-1"
    Modeline "1920x1080_85.00" 198.500 1920 1968 2000 2080 1080 1083 1088 1124 >
    Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080_85.00"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Monitor "Displayport-1"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "1920x1080_85.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver "amdgpu"
EndSection
```

With Intel integrated graphics I had to keep `Driver "amdgpu"` for some unknown reason. In my previous attempt I put `Driver "intel"` and sadly that didn't work.